# Multiplot with matplotlib without knowing the number of plots before running

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have a problem with Matplotlib's subplots. I do not know the number of subplots I want to plot beforehand, but I know that I want them in two rows. so I cannot use

```
plt.subplot(212)
```

because I don't know the number that I should provide.

It should look like this:

[image: example for plot]

Right now, I plot all the plots into a folder and put them together with illustrator, but there has to be a better way with Matplotlib. I can provide my code if I was unclear somewhere.

Comment: a DIY way would be to use `axes.set_position()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881520/alignment-of-stacked-subplots/10881881#10881881

Comment: Do you mean that you do not know the number of plots until runtime, or until you have already started processing some plots? If it is the former, you can use the explicit syntax: `plt.subplot(2, n_rows, 2)` where n_rows would be your number of plots / 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding is that you only know the number of plots at runtime and hence are struggling with the shorthand syntax, e.g.:

```
plt.subplot(121)
```

Thankfully, to save you having to do some awkward math to figure out this number programatically, there is another interface which allows you to use the form:

```
plt.subplot(n_cols, n_rows, plot_num)
```

So in your case, given you want `n` plots, you can do:

```
n_plots = 5 # (or however many you programatically figure out you need)
n_cols = 2
n_rows = (n_plots + 1) // n_cols
for plot_num in range(n_plots):
   ax = plt.subplot(n_cols, n_rows, plot_num)
   # ... do some plotting
```

Alternatively, there is also a slightly more pythonic interface which you may wish to be aware of:

```
fig, subplots = plt.subplots(n_cols, n_rows)
for ax in subplots:
   # ... do some plotting
```

(Notice that this was `subplots()` not the plain `subplot()`). Although I must admit, I have never used this latter interface.

HTH